# Is there a system wildcard for user documents?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcards

I'm working on a batch script that deletes folders and files and I want to know if there is a default wildcard that represents:

```
%userprofile%\Documents\
```

I know about `C:\Users\%USERNAME\Documents\` and `%userprofile%\Documents\`, but I'm looking for something like `%documents%`. I tried the `%DOCUMENTS%` wildcard, but it did nothing. Does such a wildcard exist? I haven't been able to find this information anywhere yet...

Comment: There is %HOMEPATH%, not specifically to the documents folder, but to that specific user's folder. There is a list here, but I don't see anything that covers the documents folder specifically: https://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/

Comment: Wildcards are * and ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"Wildcards are * and?"_ @Squashman. Are you wondering what the asterisk represents? There is a note for it at the bottom of my question.

Comment: You are confusing system variables with wildcard symbols. System variables are not wildcards.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware. I thought any variable wrapped in percentage signs was a wildcard. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there an environment variable for `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents`?

No. However there is nothing stopping you creating one:

```
set DOCUMENTS=%USERPROFILE%\documents
```

To make it permanent:

```
setx DOCUMENTS %USERPROFILE%\documents /m
```

Notes:

- `/m` sets the value for the local machine, so all users will see it
- `setx` requires a restart of any currently open `cmd` shells.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).